# wordpress bootstrap submenu always visible in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am using wordpress and The responsive menubar is having issues. The sub-menu links are always visible in the mobile responsive view. The operative site is [Here](http://www.shop2trip.in/)
I have checked for this issue in Google but didnt find the proper answer anywhere. Can anyone solve here please?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducable example, either in the form of a snippet,  jsfiddle.net link or similar. Posting a link to your website is not sufficient.

Comment: If you can directly look at the original website then it would be a great help. There are many css levels included. one is bootstrap, another is wordpress theme and third one is woocommerce. Please have a look at the website and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You override bootstraps css within your custom media-query in your style.css - see .dropdown-menu at line 138: display: block is the problem!

```
  .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: static;
}
```

Removing display: block should resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.... This solved my half problem. Now the submenu items collapse onclick but then they can't be hidden by clicking again on parent..... Please provide solution for that as well.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't understand the new problem. If I click onto a dropdown it collapses and the children are visible, and if I click once again then the children are hidden. I checked this via resized browser and with my phone. Did you solve this already? Because it's working as expetected.

Comment: Yes. I worked it out just recently, It was the problem of one more bootstrap class in my css file. Thanks for your concern @fen89 .

Comment: can you pls +1 my question?

Comment: Exactly what I needed +1

Answer (score 1):

Default css queries of bootstrap are bypassed by your style.css. Look at the class dropdown-menu and remove display-block in your media query of max-width: 767px. This will solve your problem.